# xcode Simulator delays the displaying of a page

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios11, swift4

Upgraded to XCode 9.2 and now my app behaves badly on the ios simulator. It still runs ok when deployed to a physical device.

The problem is that pages are taking from 10secs to 1 minute to refresh. eg after a tableview.reloadDate().  I am certain the reloading of the data is occurring immediately, it just that the page isn't being displayed until after a long delay

Interestingly if I tap the simulator screen the response is as if I tapped the refreshed (but as yet undisplayed) page.

I don't think this is an animation issue, I have made sure that in the simulator Debug menu that 'Slow Animations' is not toggled on. Also I have 'Optimize Rendering for Windows Scale' checked.

EDIT
To provide a bit more info I have provided a sample code.  If someone using Xcode 9.2 could create a Single Page App and place a tableView into the View Controller and then add the code below to the swift file and run it on the 11.2 simulator and let me know how it goes I would be very grateful.  Just be aware that when you tap on a cell it should redraw the table with the next level of data, for me this will take up to one minute.  If you tap prior to the screen being updated then the page will be redrawn immediately (but act as though you tapped on the page which hadn't been yet been drawn).

Alternatively just peruse the code and see if you can spot something that would lead to the issue.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var level = 1
let data1 = ["One - one", "One - two", "One - three"]
let data2 = ["Two - one", "Two - two", "Two - three"]
let data3 = ["Back to One"]
var data: Array<String> = Array<String>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    data = data1
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId")!
  let text = data[indexPath.row]
  cell.textLabel?.text = text
  return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  print("Cell selected from data\(level)" )
  level += 1
  if level == 2 {
    data = data2
  } else  if level == 3 {
    data = data3
  } else  if level == 4 {
    data = data1
    level = 1
  }
  tableView.reloadData()
  print("Data loaded")
}
}
```

NOTE: I know this code is rubbish, but it demonstrate the issues please do not critique its uselessness.

Comment: Reset the simulator and then try again.

Comment: Thanks, but I reset and still the same behavior

Comment: If it is using core graphics, gradients, blend mode, maps, and animation heavy I have noticed poor performance. They originally left off OpenGL. They fixed it but the performance is slow. The app I am working on runs faster on device than on simulator

Comment: Just refreshing a tableView takes up to a minute.  The data is loaded immediately but there is a 1 minute gap before the page is actually redrawn.

Comment: Wow. Are you sure it is on the main thread when you call the reload?

Comment: Yes, I have now just created a little example project with just a tableView. I change the contents of the tableview when a cell is tapped using a reloadData().  It takes for ever to refresh.  However, if I use a tabbar button to change the contents it happens immediately.

Comment: Please disregard comment regarding tabbar button, it behaves identically (in terms of time) as tapping the cell.

Comment: @crackles I have the same issue and did a video demonstrating this: https://streamable.com/vkhwo
did you find any solution to fix this?

Comment: @moritzw I still have issue. Good to know I’m not the only one. I am using my iPhone and iPad to get around the problem for now. It’s a pain

Comment: @crackles do you still have this issue? I tested it on 2 Macs with the same hardware (i5, Intel HD3000, 8GB DDR3) and the simulator is not running fine on both. On the 3rd Mac (i7, Intel Iris, 16GB) the simulator works normal.

Comment: @moritzw Hmmm I'm using Mac Mini (Mid 2011) I5 8GB DDR3. That's a big coincidence.  It would be great to get a comment from anybody else out there that is using similar HW that IS/IS NOT having same issue?

Comment: @crackles I did a full reset of my Mac Mini today and I still have this issue. I think it is the hardware/software combination that is causing the error.

Comment: @moritzw Just submitted a bug report.  Will report back here