# On Simulator (iPhone) scenes changes are loading very slow. Why?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, slowdown

Recently the Xcode simulator is processing scene changes very slow or sometimes just crashing.  This occurs when my spaceship navigates to the home base (which is just a rectangle) that is programmed to change to the next scene (stage) upon collision.  It's funny because another rectangle (that represents level select) pretty much loads up ok when my spaceship navigates to it (upon collision), as in the level select screen shows up as expected.  This problem has cropped up when I recently added jpeg backgrounds to the stages and animated them using colorise and fade actions.  Could this be the issue?  I did test not adding the background jpeg as a child to the scene so it reverted back to how it was but I was still experiencing the slow down as described prior.  I'm using Xcode 9.2 on a pretty high spec iMac so I don't think its my RAM or CPU in question, I wouldn't think anyway.

Please can you assist with a plausible solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The simulator is slow at the best of times, but it sounds like you are using too much memory for your image - is the file large? Are you loading it into memory in a bad way?

Comment: Hi Mikkel, in total the folder of Jpegs is 2.2mb and I'm using a sprite atlas to put them in.

Comment: How do I know if I'm using too much memory?  How do I place the JPEGS into my Xcode project in a memory feasible way?  What if it's not the JPEGS that are causing the slow down with the simulator?  Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Use the Activity Monitor to see how much memory the process is using, Try it without loading the images, and try it with smaller images and compare the difference

Comment: The memory performance is not telling me much, it goes up and down kind of randomly if you ask me, so I can't really tell judging by that.  However, there really didn't seem to be a difference in speed when I used a smaller image file (25kb) compared to the original like (150kb), tested on 1 scene.  What does that say?  Also when I just bypassed the image altogether by not even adding it to the scene (so no background image) again the speed was the same, still pretty slow.  Even when I took off the colorize action on the background image, speed still slow.  Why oh why??

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's more to do with the actual simulator.  Is there a way you can speed up simulator performance, maybe it's got a backload or something or maybe like with the internet its cookies need clearing (if it has any) you see what I mean right?  Also is simulator performance necessarily the way it will run on an actual phone?

Comment: Myself and at least one other person has been having issue with simulator displaying slowly since upgrade to 9.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179107/xcode-simulator-delays-the-displaying-of-a-page  In my case the simulator acted like it redrew the screen but visually it took up to one minute to replace it.

Comment: Right! Add to that, It was almost like the simulator was half crashing when he had to initiate a new scene load and then re-booted itself or something.  I wasn't having this problem before the upgrade, so I think Apple is messing up here and need to fix this prob otherwise developers are losing time and money not completing apps.  We can't work with a decrepit simulator, I've put my whole game on hold so its just too frustrating. SOLVE THIS SOMEONE!