# IOS Xcode 10 Simulator Slow Redraw

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode10

I've just started to learn the basics of developing apps for IOS devices. I'm following a Stanford University course on YouTube but hit a snag straight away on lesson 1. The series of lectures develop a basic game displaying a set of cards that you have to flip over and match pairs. It's really simple stuff at this stage!

The problem is, when I run the code using the Simulator, I tap a card to flip it over but the refresh is delayed by up to a minute. There are many posts on the web complaining about the Simulator being slow but I've not found anything that identifies this exact problem. This older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179107/xcode-simulator-delays-the-displaying-of-a-page) looks to be a similar issue but remains unsolved.

In trying to figure out what was wrong I decided to time the refresh delay and opened the system Time & Date window so I could roughly count the number of seconds. I clicked on a card and waited for the refresh. Then I noticed something odd... The card redraws as the system clock ticks over the minute. If I click the card with the clock at 59 seconds the refresh happens after ~1 second. If I click it at 1 second past the minute it takes ~59 seconds.

I should also point out that I know of the Slow Animations option and this is toggled off.

So, my question is... What is this artificial delay in the refresh and how do I fix/remove it on my IPhone simulator?

Comment: This seems unlikely to be a Simulator problem; it is probably a flaw in your game code somewhere. It sounds suspiciously like you specified 60 somewhere you meant to specify 1/60, resulting in a framerate of 60 seconds per frame instead of 60 frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

I had simulator refresh problem too and this fixed it:

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint X
```

Where X is:

0 = auto

1 = Metal

2 = OpenCL

3 = OpenGL

You must restart simulator after this command.
In my case with AMD GPU, it was number 1 to use metal. Simulator is very fast again now.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @hbdev, I have tried each of the values for X, but sadly no change in the behaviour of my simulator.